# AngularJS - Dropdown being populated with an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm having some trouble understanding a dropdown functionality in Angular.

I've tried following these posts from StackOverflow but I'm stuck:

[How can I populate a select dropdown list from a JSON feed with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs)

[Angular js Populate dropdown with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400656/angular-js-populate-dropdown-with-json)

[populate dropdown AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922026/populate-dropdown-angularjs)

The only way I was able to populate the dropdown is with all the values showing in every single row (defeating its purpose):
[image: Current dropdown]+
My code so far:

HTML:

```
<div align = "left" ng-controller='DemoCtrl'> 
<select ng-model="tiposProduto" >
<option value="">Selecione o tipo de produto:</option>
<option ng-repeat ="selectedTestAccount in testAccounts"  value="item.Id"> {{testAccounts}}>
</select>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
    $scope.testAccounts = [];

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '//localhost:8080/RestfulWebservice/rs/service/getTodosTiposProduto'
    }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.testAccounts = result.tiposProduto;
    });
});
</script>
```

So, I'm not sure what the ng-repeat line should be doing. Both "items" and "selectedTestAccount" are undefined if I try to log them in the console.

The scope is this (the testAccount values are the ones I wanted to populate as rows):[image: Scope returned]

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: SelectedTestAccount should not be declared in controller. And what is item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put "selectedTestAccount" inside expression in option.

```
<div align = "left" ng-controller='DemoCtrl'> 
<select ng-model="tiposProduto" >
<option value="">Selecione o tipo de produto:</option>
<option ng-repeat ="selectedTestAccount in testAccounts"  value="item.Id"> {{selectedTestAccount}}>
</select>
 </div>
```